# OSX: Is there a way to make an .app file a screensaver?

Tags: macos, screensaver, osx-mavericks

I don't use Macs regularly at all and need port a screensaver from windows to Mac. I've successfully made .app file that runs as expected on OSX.

On windows I can just rename an .exe to .scr and install/run it.   Is there a process in OSX to do something similar with my .app file?

Comment: Please provide more info. What have you done so far "successfully"? To partly answer your question: __sometimes__ OS X __will__ respond desirably to renaming file extensions. Depends on what you're trying to do. Did you make a .app file with automator or Xcode? Documentation on screen savers https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=make+a+screen+saver . Also, if you go here in Finder on  your computer HDNAME>SYSTEM>LIBRARY>SCREENSAVERS you can see the (three for me) types of screensavers currently used by OS X and their extensions.

Comment: By the way, technically, a .app is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in `OS X Screen saver` functionality? For example http://osxdaily.com/2010/04/30/make-a-screensaver-out-of-your-own-images-in-mac-os-x/

If you wish to write a screensaver app, this article is a good start: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000088.php